# Identify Image in Excel - VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, vba, macros

I have an Excel sheet, and I want to create some macros using VBA.

Specifically, I want to change an image with a predefined one, every time I press a button or every time I press on an image.

The first problem i encounter, is that... I don't know how to define the identity of the image to be changed in VBA! I don't see any way to extract the name or some ID of the image, so as to use it in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: it's a `shape`. Start with referencing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to approach this problem.

1. Create a form with all the controls on it, including the image (this would be the easiest way)
2. Place an image control directly on the excelsheet, along with other controls (this is prone to users causing to delete the content.

If you go for option 1, From VBA, create a new form and draw your controls on there. You then need to create a small public sub that says: Form1.show (where Form1 is the name of your form)
If you go for option 2, you have to enable the appropriate toolbar in Excel first.

There are 2 form toolbars available. Although both work, one is easier to work with, because it looks and feels exactly like the one from the VBA form.

Once you place an image control using that toolbar and you are in design mode, you can click the image control and from the properties, give it a name. This name can then be used from your VBA macro using: application.sheet(1).`name of image`.image = .... or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Will try it, but even solely providing a starting point is enough for my purpose. Thank you.